# What does this crying icon of the task pane mean?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

Recently, I often see this (crying) icon in the taskpane after opening my tool in Excel Online Chrome. In the following screenshot, it is after clicking on "Spreadsheet Verificator" of [10 Studio](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA200000139?tab=Overview).

The DevTools does not give any useful information.

Does anyone know what this icon means? Should I inspect anything in my add-in?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It likely means that the page the application was trying to display crashed or something similar (the desired  information failed to load or otherwise couldn't be displayed). While not this exact icon, Chrome has a similar design for its "Aw, snap!" (crashed) error pages.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Microsoft Office products in your browser, you get this failure symbol. It's google-chrome-only and means that the widget on the right (spreadsheet optimizer) could not be loaded (or initialised).

You should try using a real application, not this in-browser BS. The sadface smiley is by no means a threat.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is your answer better than the one posted almost three years ago?

Comment: Right, 3 years is a long time. I admit I just went over questions that are open and tried to answere one. In this case, OP is unlikely to ever return and accept an answere